# Sustituir colores según contenido PHP

Tags: php

Estoy editando un sistema de reservas y tengo una duda.
El tema es que me gustaría que según el título que le ponga salga de un color u otro. Tengo este código:

```
                                    $color_titulo = 'style="background-color:#EAFFCF"'; //Predeterminamos un código de color y se sustituye si se cumple alguna de las siguientes reglas
                                if($reservadas >= $clase_celda->num_plazas){
                                    $color_titulo = 'style="background-color:#E80909;color:#fff"';
                                }
                                if(strpos(strtoupper($clase_celda->nombre), "General") !== false){
                                    $color_titulo = 'style="background-color:#D7F6FF"';
                                }
                                if($clase_celda->nombre=='Normal'){
                                    $color_titulo = 'style="background-color:#a5b1c1"';
                                }
```

Cuando el texto aparece "general" acompañado de algo me sustituye y actúa bien, pero si quiero usar el "normal", sólo debe de poner "Normal" para que cambie el color de fondo, si uso el mismo formato que en el anterior donde pone "General" se me cambian en todos por completo.

No sé si me he explicado bien

En resumen quiero que si por ejemplo pone "Normal 10:00" o lo que sea acompañado me lo incluya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia la sentencia:

```
if($clase_celda->nombre=='Normal')
     $color_titulo = 'style="background-color:#a5b1c1"';
```

por (cuando la palabra siempre es "Normal"):

```
if($clase_celda->nombre==='Normal')
    $color_titulo = 'style="background-color:#a5b1c1"';
```

o cuando "Normal" es un substring (por ejemplo "Normal 10:00")

```
if (strpos($clase_celda->nombre, 'Normal') !== false) {
    $color_titulo = 'style="background-color:#a5b1c1"';
}
```

También puedes convertir la cadena a mayúsculas como lo haces en la sentencia anterior:

```
if (strpos(strtoupper($clase_celda->nombre), 'Normal') !== false) {
    $color_titulo = 'style="background-color:#a5b1c1"';
}
```

Comment: creo que su problema se genera por que esta modificando la variable, digamos primero es rojo, luego verde, y ese ultimo color se **aplica a todo**, pero el quiere conservar, los dos colores para dos regiones

Comment: cada if me parece que lo definió bien, el único caso en el que podría entrar a todos los if es cuando cada condición se cumpla

Comment: mi duda es esta parte: *si uso el mismo formato que en el anterior donde pone "General" se me cambian en todos al completo*

Comment: el error principal era usar el operador ==, [aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7551995/4987172) un ejemplo. Pudo haber entrado siempre a esa ultima condición.

Answer (score 0):

Vale, la solución ha sido usando en todos de esta forma:

```
if(strpos(strtoupper($clase_celda->nombre), "General") !== false) {
$color_titulo = 'style="background-color:#D7F6FF"';
}
```

Pero con el "GENERAL" EN MAYÚSCULAS, si no, no funcionaba.

PD: cómo puedo añadir que sean dos palabras en la misma, por ejemplo "general" o "general 2". estoy probando con `"GENERAL" or "GENERAL2"`
pero no

Comment: Pero esa fue la respuesta que yo te dí.

Comment: No, perdona, me expliqué mal con el "general" me refería a esto:                                                       if(strpos(strtoupper($clase_celda->nombre), "General" or "normal") !== false) {
$color_titulo = 'style="background-color:#D7F6FF"';
}´             osea, dos palabras diferentes con el mismo atributo. gracias